# Commenting a particular question crashes Android Chrome

Tags: bug, comments

I wanted to add a comment to [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/65976/how-does-this-bird-trap-work).

> Either those are very small trees, or that is a very large monk.

When I hit "add comment", Chrome crashes.

Bizarrely, it's only this question. Trying to add comments to other History questions don't cause a crash, nor do attempts to add comments on other sites. Also, I can add a comment to the answer posted for the question!

The technical details can be followed on Meta Stack Exchange at [Trying to comment on a particular question on the full site crashes Android Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369434/trying-to-comment-on-a-particular-question-on-the-full-site-crashes-android-chro)

Comment: I don't actually use Chrome on SE sites. While I know SE employees do sometimes look at our quaint little site meta, you may have better luck asking a technical software question like this on the main meta site: http://meta.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Oh, and I'd suggest mentioning exactly what version of Chrome you are using. Not being a Chrome user, I don't know how to get that, but I'd imagine there'd be an "About" box you can bring up somewhere.

Comment: (Of course you also noticed that the monk may not b a monk at all, although he is indeed a giant compared  to the trees—and that the little birds are actually quite big as well? Now imagine which trees he used to make his wooden device…)